# autoResizingMask for inputAccessoryView not working

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm trying to cope with iPhone X with `inputAccessoryView`. I've added a view to my `ViewController` like so:

CustomView

[image]

I've defined an outlet and attached to it. Returned the same view as `inputAccessoryView` like so:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldContainer: UIView!

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        return textFieldContainer
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textFieldContainer.autoresizesSubviews = true
    }
}
```

I've made sure to add constraints relative to safe area. Here are my constraints:

Constraints

[image]
Adjusted `autoResizingMask` in SB like so:

AutoResizingMask

[image]

However, it's still not working. Here's the output:

Output

[image]

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike for table view cells, there is no support for dynamic height calculation in input accessory views, as far as I know.

You could use a fixed height for the accessory view.

But I assume, that you want just to change either top, bottom, or height constraint in interface builder and the change is reflected after the next build.

What you could do is, to use a custom view class where you connect your top, bottom and height constraints.

Then override `intrinsicContentSize` and return the sum of the three constraint constants.

```
class TextFieldContainer: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var topConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {

        let contentHeight =
            self.topConstraint.constant
                + self.heightConstraint.constant
                + self.bottomConstraint.constant

        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: contentHeight)
    }
}
```

Your layout hierarchy could be simplified and look like this:

[image: view layout]

The autoresizing mask could look like this:

[image: autoresizing mask]

The final result would behave like the following then:

[image: input accessory view]

Comment: That looks promising. I'll try that out and accept if it works. Cheers.

Comment: Works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You're giving textfield height and also bottom constraint, try to remove bottom constraint for textfield

Comment: It didn't fix the issue though. The issue is `inputAccessoryView` being fixed height. Not flexible height.